# Using "Bind" for simple ajax up/down vote function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax up/down vote function.

I would like to rebind this "voteClickEvent" on success of ajax call for the opposite vote. Must I put this in a seperate function in the success call? Or can I do this more elegantly?

```
    var voteClickEvent = function() {
        var upOrDown = $(this).attr('id');
        var that = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {upOrDown: upOrDown, action: "updateVote"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.output);
                that.unbind("click");
                that.css("cursor", "default");
                if (data.output == "up") {
                    $("#down").bind("click", voteClickEvent);
                } else {
                    $("#up").bind("click", voteClickEvent);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    $("#up, #down").bind("click", voteClickEvent);
```

Comment: there is no error @Dinesh, However the bind is not working on success.

Comment: looks like it is just adding another click event, is there a bind only if not already binded function?

Comment: your code should actually be adding a second click handler to the other element. WHy do you need to bind twice?

Comment: @charlietfl is there a way to check if the click event is already bound? so i can only "re-bind" in this case?

Comment: In your handler you unbind the click event from #up (for example), but the #down button is still bound, so why you bind it again to the same handler?

Comment: I guess i can just unbind both selectors on either click. and then rebind the opposite of what is clicked. answered my own question :) sry guys. thanks for the help.

Comment: Would be simpler to just toggle a class on elements and not do anything in click handler if class exists. Otherwise unbind both

Comment: @ROX the unbind will be only for the pressed button, not both of them.